# Can I use EE tags in RTE Editor?

Tags: channel-entries, richtext

I am trying to use EE tags inside RTE Editor.  But it is not working. So Can i use EE tags inside RTE Editor? if yes then how can i use?
Currently using below in Textarea (Rich Text)

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}

### {title}

{/exp:channel:entries}

But it is displaying as it is.
So Please how can i use? Looking for quick response

Comment: What are you trying to do? Generally putting EE code in entries is a symptom of a bigger issue - either not understanding EE completely or missing a better way to do something. Entries should hold content, and EE code should go in templates or snippets.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use tags within an RTE field. But depending what you are trying to do, you may find [Solspace Preparse](http://www.solspace.com/docs/preparse) useful